# Running Flask application with twisted

Tags: python, flask, twisted.web

My server.py is as follows,

```
    from flask import Flask, jsonify, Response, redirect
    import json
    from UIAccess import UIAccess
    app=Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/Hello/<username>')
    def id_no(username):
        id= obj.get_id(username)
        return json.dumps(id)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        obj=UIAccess()
        app.run(threaded=True)
```

when I run the program and load the page using my browser I am able to view the output of 'id_no' but if I run the same program using twisted with the command,

```
    twistd web --wsgi server.app
```

I get an internal server error, I am wondering whether this is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: @AndréLaszlo http 500 internal server error..

Comment: Try logging the error to see where things go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You only create `obj` if `__name__ == '__main__'`, which it does not when you run with something besides `python server.py`.  But the `id_no` view depends on `obj` being defined, so it fails.  Move `obj = UIAccess()` out of the guard block.